# Bash If statement within while loop executes even when condition not met

Tags: bash, google-chrome-os

I have been using a bash script within ChromeOS to record screen brightness every 5 minutes as well as change and record the brightness if it changes.

```
#!/bin/sh

#This script will collect brightness every 5 minutes
#If brightness is not at desired setting, script will correct and note time changed

i=13
time=$(date +%H%M)
bright=$(backlight_tool --get_brightness_percent)

echo "start time is "$time >> brightness_log.txt
while [ $i -ne 1 ]; do

    sleep 300 
    backlight_tool --get_brightness_percent >> brightness_log.txt
    i=$(( $i-1 ))

        if [ $bright != 60.5 ]; then
            backlight_tool --set_brightness_percent=60.5
            echo "Brightness changed at "$time >> brightness_log.txt
        else
            break
        fi 
done
exit
```

The script works, however even when brightness is 60.5, the if statement will execute and echo "Brightness changed at " with the same repeated time.

If the brightness IS equal to 60.5, why is the if statement executing and not skipping to the break?

Comment: could you post the output of `printf '%q\n' "$(backlight_tool --get_brightness_percent)"` to let us see what's exactly inside the variable?

Comment: Output tells me that `printf: %q: invalid directive`

Comment: Oh, then change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I do now get the correct output now and `printf` will now echo the brightness. But the script is still executing the if statement and not skipping to the break. So my problem is still remains. This may have something to do with the fact that I am using ChromeOS.

Answer (score 1):

You never update the variable `bright` it's set outside of the loop. Move the assignment inside the while loop, and it will work.

```
while [ "$i" -gt 1 ]; do
  bright=$(backlight_tool --get_brightness_percent)
  ..
done
```

Please validate your script with [`shellcheck`](https://www.shellcheck.net/), as you have many pitfalls present, one being not quoting parameter expansion:

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 10:
echo "start time is "$time >> brightness_log.txt
                     ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

Comment: I moved the `bright` variable inside the while loop and double quoted `$i` within the while loop bracket, however output remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

Within the while loop I inserted

```
echo "$bright" | grep "60.5" -q 
gcode=$?
```

I then changed the if statement to

```
if [[ $gcode -eq 0 ]]; then
```

The if statement now only executes as intended.